# Is there any way to increment past an array element in Python? (Like how you can with pointer arithmetic in C?)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have

```
arr = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I want to use the ...5, 4, 3, 2, 1] part of the array in a recursive call while keeping the 6 in the array (at its current position) for future use.

It feels very similar to pointer arithmetic in C, I'm just not sure how to implement something like that in Python (ver 3.7). I'm lost as to how to preserve the 6 in the array at it's position, which is essential as the array needs to be maintained in sorted descending order.

Any guidance on how to get around this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements of the `arr` list in the following manner while not disturbing the elements of it

```
>>> arr[2:]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> arr[1:]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> arr
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> arr[2:4]
[4, 3]
```

List indexing doesn't affect the elements inside. I hope this answers your question

Comment: Perfect. But using that method is there any way I could then get back the full array if I sent something like arr[n:] in a function call, where n is an arbitrary number?

Comment: You can! As long as you are not deleting or updating the original list! Furthermore , the operations I have mentioned are not affecting the list anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a part of an array in a recursive call without changing the original array using start and end index.
`arr=[6,5,4,3,2,1]`, now if you want to use arr from index=1 then just pass
start and end i.e, `fun(arr, start, end)` in the function `fun` where, start=1 and end=length-1, this will not modify the original array and at the same time you can use array from start to end in recursive calls.